# Non-existent zip code but still get shipping methods

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

Can someone explain to me why for a non-existent zip I still get shipping methods. Let's say I choose US, Florida and 32005. Using a service I get that zip code is not found but in Magento I can get an estimation shipping cost. Is it wrong to just tell that zip is wrong or should I leave it like it is now?

Comment: This highly depends on the shipping method. Many shipping methods doesn't check the ZIP and only calculate the costs depending on the state. What shipping method do you use?

Comment: @Fabian - Table rates

Comment: There is no check. If you want a check you need a intelligent and learning implementation, like asking the API of dhl, ups, TNT etc. every time

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - I am not sure I understand. What can DHL tell me about a zip (like in my example) which doesn't exist in US?

Comment: DHL has a WebAPI you can request shipping costs from and I'm sure (but don't know) they check the address before calculating the costs

Answer (score 1):

Not all shipping methods validate the address when fetching rate quotes.  For example, FedEx has an Address Validation Service (AVS) which is separate from the Rate Service.  AVS catches the invalid addresses, but the Rate Service does not.

If you want to ensure the address and ZIP code are valid, you can run the address through AVS first.